# Code execution hangs on select() when trying to create a TCP server

Tags: sockets, timeout, winsock

I am totally inexperienced when it comes to socket programming, so when I needed a web server I could use to bounce data between a NodeMCU and my desktop, I found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kc1kwm1WyVM&t=1s&ab_channel=SloanKelly).

I am currently using the [code he has linked in the description of his video](https://github.com/codehoose/barebones-webserver/tree/release/video-2/bbws), completely unaltered.
An excerpt of that code where I am having issues is below, the specific issue near the bottom:
`

```
int TcpListener::init()
{
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        return wsOk;
    }
    m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (m_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        DBG("Failed to create a socket: Error Below");
        DBG(WSAGetLastError());
        return WSAGetLastError();
    }
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(m_port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, m_ipAddress, &hint.sin_addr);

    if (bind(m_socket, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        DBG("Failed to bind IP & port to Socket: Error Below");
        DBG(WSAGetLastError());
        return WSAGetLastError();
    }
    if (listen(m_socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        DBG("Failed to tell WINSOCK socket is for listening: Error Below");
        DBG(WSAGetLastError());
        return WSAGetLastError();
    }
    FD_ZERO(&m_master);
    FD_SET(m_socket, &m_master);

    return 0;
}

int TcpListener::run()
{
    bool running = true;

    while (running)
    {
        fd_set copy = m_master;

        DBG("Point A"); // <- THIS POINT IS REACHED
        int socketCount = select(0, &copy, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
        DBG("Point B"); // <- THIS POINT IS NEVER REACHED
        // Etcetera
    }
```

`

The issue I am encountering is code execution seems to hang indefinitely on `int socketCount = select(0, &copy, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);`. Given this is the exact code he runs in the video and it works flawlessly there, I don't understand what the issue is. I have tried stepping through the code line by line with the debugger, and upon reaching the line in question, execution simply freezes. I can't continue, I can't step, and to leave the debugger I have to force quit the program.

Ideally I would like to resolve this issue, but ultimately I am just trying to wirelessly send data between an application running on my PC, and a NodeMCU. If anyone knows a better way to do this, I am also totally open to suggestions.

Comment: select will block until something connects to the server. Thus, likely nothing is even trying to connect to the server or the attempt is blocked by some firewall before reaching the server. Unfortunately nothing in your question indicates that you even try with connecting something, so you might not even be aware of this requirement.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I wasn't aware this was a requirement, though I did attempt to connect to the server via Putty. I'm not sure if a firewall is blocking my connection, or if I just did something wrong, but I was unable to connect.

Comment: that's a different type of blocking (network firewall); select() "blocks" the process running the code